# Can we get duplicate offset value while receiving messages from azure-eventhub once data get expired from event hub?

Tags: azure, azureservicebus, azure-servicebus-queues, azure-eventhub, azure-servicebus-topics

Messages will be stored on `Event Hub` for a specific time interval. Once this time expires messages are removed automatically. As `offset` values defines the position of event in the `partition`, I'm confused if I'll get the same `offset value` next time (after data expires from partition). If so then what is difference between `offset` and event `sequence` of partition?

Answer (score 2):

**TLDR: You will NEVER receive the same offset - even after the data is expired from EventHubs.**

**[Offset](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/microsoft.servicebus.messaging.eventdata.offset.aspx)**: is the address (or pointer or cursor) of your Event on an EventHub Partition. Getting into implementation details, **Offset is a struct on our Service (whose underlying value is stuffed into 64 bits - for optimization - and hence a [c# long](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ctetwysk.aspx) in the client) - representing the address of the event in our service's underlying file-system**. If you need to replay the EventHub partition events from a particular point - you will need the Offset. That is exactly what it is built for.

**[SequenceNumber](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/microsoft.servicebus.messaging.eventdata.sequencenumber.aspx)**: is a monotonously increasing number that is **STAMPED** on every EventData - on Eventhubs Service - to represent the order of events. It is sequential and is intended be used to represent - **length of the stream** - no. of events on the Partition - by querying [GetPartitionRuntimeInfo](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/microsoft.servicebus.messaging.eventhubclient.getpartitionruntimeinformationasync.aspx) and diff. between [LastEnqueuedSeqNo.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/microsoft.servicebus.messaging.partitionruntimeinformation.lastenqueuedsequencenumber.aspx) and [BeginSeqNo.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/microsoft.servicebus.messaging.partitionruntimeinformation.beginsequencenumber.aspx). The receiver could get current received offset (from [EventData.Offset](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/microsoft.servicebus.messaging.eventdata.offset.aspx)) - which if you compare with [LastEnqueuedSeqNo.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/microsoft.servicebus.messaging.partitionruntimeinformation.lastenqueuedsequencenumber.aspx) can give - **howmuch the receiver is lagging behind by** - this is the prime reason why this was built for.

HTH!
Sree